# The different ways for creating a new Spring MVC project explanation (only explanation)

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, sts

**This is not an opinion-based question.** I just want some explanation about the difference between these ways for making a spring mvc project.

- Creating a spring project using STS
- Creating a Spring boot project with eclipse and add "Spring Web"
- Creating a dynamic project
- Creating a maven project and choose dynamic web project / spring project

I already know the importance of using Maven but if i create a spring boot project i can manage also my dependencies in pom.xml if i'm not wrong

Comment: As commented already they all do the same, only te way the `pom.xml`/`build.gradle` is managed is different.

Comment: so the only difference is how we manage our dependencies as i understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all the same at the and. In case you use STS to create a project, you just have to mention the dependencies you need and STS will go to spring.io and download the maven project file with all the dependencies and bring the ready to run project in your STS IDE. Also we use maven to make dependency management easy. It's all about people's preference and comfort. But I myself prefer maven.